# C++ custom string split?

Tags: c++

I am still a newbie to c++; I was wondering why the code i wrote for a custom string split fuction does not work? (it splits by char and not string) I think there is something wrong with memcpy in the second instance?

```
char** strsplit(const char *s, const char splitboi)
{
    const int LEN = length(s);
    int segs = 0;
    char *segstore, **out;
    for (int chrs=0; chrs<=LEN; chrs++)
    {
        if(*(s+chrs) != splitboi)
        {char* temp = chrs==0 ? (char*)"" : segstore;
            segstore = new char[chrs+1];
            memcpy(&segstore, &temp, sizeof(char*));
            segstore[chrs] = *(s+chrs);}
        else if(*(s+chrs) == splitboi)
        {char **temp = out;
            out = new char* [segs+1];
            memcpy(&out, &temp, sizeof(char**)); //something wrong with this
            out[segs] = segstore;
            segs++;}
    }

    delete segstore;
    cout << out[0] << '\n';
    return out;
}
```

Comment: why are you ignoring all the C++ features and using, what is essentially C (except for the output). that's making your life much harder.

Comment: oh, im trying to learn the basics before library functions and templates.

Comment: the basics of C++ are different from the basics of C. You're using a lot of programming patterns that are idiomatic C but considered bad practice in C++ (e.g., pointer math). C++ is not an extension of C. It is a different language that only looks similar.

Comment: ohhhh. so I think I should just use the indexes?

Comment: To split a string, use a std::string, and use parts of the string class to figure out how to identify substrings you want to split. You'll find the class methods here. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string . Then, you can go on to be more advanced and learn about string_view, which is a more time-efficient way to manipulate strings. Find a good textbook on C++ like something by Stroustrup (the inventor of C++). Many online teaching sources are poor quality.

Comment: The standard library is an integral part of modern C++. You should learn using the library. Eventually, when you become more advanced, you can try making your own algorithms. By then, you'll have learned about RAII and other C++ features that allow you to do fancy stuff without shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: I still want to know what was wrong with the code, if you could humor me.

Comment: There's lots wrong there. For instance, you're trying to copy characters with memcpy, but you're using the size of a pointer for the number of characters to copy `sizeof(char*)`. That just seems wrong. The third parameter is the number of characters to copy.

Comment: One bomb for later: `temp = chrs==0 ? (char*)"" : segstore;`: you mix the dynamically allocated buffers with constants coming from string literals.

Comment: You are studying bad things, for example how to shot into your leg and to leak your memory.

Comment: ok, thank you for taking time to help me. I just found this textbook in my garage by Victor Shtern, would you recommend it? https://www.amazon.com/Core-C-Software-Engineering-Approach/dp/0130857297

Comment: If you stick on C, you can use std::strtok. It does exactly what you want.